# Vuforia: UserDefinedTargets is better than ImageTargets database?

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm experimenting with Vuforia. It's going pretty well so far.

Previously I've had the ImageTarget demo working with my own targets, so I know I can get this to work for my own purposes. I also realise targets should have a good "star rating" so that Vuforia can successfully track them.

**However, the following experiment is confusing me:**

I create my own target database using the [Target Manager](https://developer.vuforia.com/target-manager), with one target, which shows up as ZERO star rating. I know Vuforia likes high star ratings, but bear with me. As I expected the ImageTargets app does not seem to recognize my target image. No surprises there really given the ZERO star rating.

However, if instead I run the UserDefinedTargets demo and I take a "live" image of the same target, Vuforia is perfectly able to track the target !

Can anyone explain why this might be the case and how I can fix the problem?

Ideally, I would like to use ImageTargets as this allows me to load in databases as I please.

Alternatively, I would like to be able to store a database captured within the UserDefinedTargets app which I can reuse at a later stage.

Overall, I'd like to know why using the Target Manager doesn't work, but using the UserDefinedTarget app does work, and how I might be able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than add this to the question, which is already quite lengthy, I thought it better to put it as an answer, although I'm open to other comments and answers!

I think the UserDefinedTarget app may recognize the images "better" because directly after the user defined target image is taken, the camera (i.e. mobile phone) is in the correct position already. This does not, however, explain the excellent "re-recognition" rate, i.e. if the camera is moved away from the target and then brought back over the target, the UserDefinedTargets app recognizes the target instantly every time.

Hmmm...